# Delete rows with index higher than X with the same value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I've got page for every account that displays last 10 logins with IP's and date. I need only last 10 of them for every account so I'd like to delete 11th, 12th, 13th row with the same `account_id` value. My table structure:

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+
| id | account_id |    ipv4    | timestamp  |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
| 25 |    9977930 | 1299288404 | 1362261821 |
| 26 |    9982862 | 1604359422 | 1362262365 |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
```

I tried something like:

```
DELETE t1 FROM `lastlogin` t1
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT `account_id`
  FROM `lastlogin`
  LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
) t2 on t2.account_id = t1.account_id AND t2.value = t1.value
WHERE t2.value is null;
```

But my select statement is wrong and the rest is also bad. I don't have good idea, how to do this except adding new column for index, and experience with more advanced SQL... Could somebody construct this query?

Comment: I'm a little bit puzzled by the 'value' column in your query. It's not in your table description.

Comment: I know - it's just a piece of code that I copied>paste and tried to make it work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the row number function, so:

```
     Delete t1 from
       (select accountid, 
        row_number() over (partition by accountid, order by accountid,                    
       Timestamp desc) as r 
       From lastlogin ) t1 
     where t1.r > 10
```

Hopefully this syntax is correct, essentially you use the row number function to create a number that increments for every different ip in descending time order and resets for each different account.

This assumes you want the most recent ips and each ip is distinct. If the ips are not distinct partition by time stamp or Id. Run the select first!

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by accountid, order by accountid, timesta' at line 3

Comment: That's because he's give you the MSSQL version. You want the mysql version of deleting using a rownum.

http://www.explodybits.com/2011/11/mysql-row-number/

Comment: Sorry, yeah there might be a syntax error - i didn't try it but know the technique works so my suggestion is to investigate row_number and make it work for you. Cheers

Comment: I used MySQL tag in this question. I don't know how to convert this.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in the query that populates in the first place.

You have the timestamp.

```
SELECT TOP 10 

...

ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

That'll get your list to display in descending order, though.  You can flip the order in a few different ways.

Comment: MySQL does not support `TOP 10` clauses for SELECTs

Comment: You use LIMIT function instead at the end of the query.